# G Suite Shared Drive(Team Drive) Role management

Tags: google-workspace, google-drive-shared-drive

A person sets a trigger with manager level.Now that person has been downgraded from manager role to viewer role in g suite shared drive. What will happen to the trigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is the role relevant to the Google Admin Console roles? I mean there are some custom schemas that you can set for your organization and you can add one as a manager but that does not means that it has a Super Admin role.

If was a Super Admin and the trigger has something to do an API that only a Super Admin can use then it may stop working, now if the trigger has nothing to do with any of these APIs like the Admin SDK it should keep running.

You can provide a sample of the trigger or explain what it does to provide you a better response but I hope this helps. Greetings

Comment: I am glad it is helpful, please consider upvote or accept it as an answer. Greetings.

Comment: Hey Mario, will you please provide the link where can I get more details regarding team drives.

Comment: Now Team Drives has been renamed to Shared Drives. Here is an article from their Learning Center https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9310351?hl=en I hope it helps you.